# How to get the list of matplotlib.lines.Line2D objects from plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter

Currently I'm doing this:

```
my_list = []
for x,y in zip(xs, ys):
   my_list.extend(ax.plot(x, y, linestyle = '', marker = 'o'))
```

because I want to access each line2d object separately. Is there a way to call ***ax.plot*** or ***ax.scatter*** once and somehow get the list of all line2d objects?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the container that holds the lines in a plot. A plot has many containers such as figure and axes. This is actually easy to do, just plot the lines, and then access them with ax.lines. The later will be a list of the [Line2D](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_color) objects.

Here is a simple example that demonstrates this container functionality by accessing the lines in a plot and using the matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_color() function.

[image: Link to plot image (I can't put images in posts yet)]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))    # define fig and axes

x = np.linspace(-20,20) # make some x values between -20 and 20
f_x = np.sin(x/4)       # make some y values that are f(x) = sin(x/4)
g_x = np.cos(x/4)       # make some y values that are g(x) = cos(x/4)

ax.plot(x, f_x, linewidth=2.5, label='f(x)') # plot f(x)
ax.plot(x, g_x, linewidth=2.5, label='g(x)') # plot g(x)

ax.lines[0].set_color('blue')
ax.lines[1].set_color('red')

#add titles, x labels, y labels, legend
title   = ax.set_title('Example plot', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
xlabels = ax.set_xlabel('x_values')
ylabels = ax.set_ylabel('y_values')
legend  = ax.legend(fontsize=14)
```

You can learn more about containers by reviewing the [Artist Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html#object-containers) in the matplotlib documentation.